# Color on background image not placing

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to place a transparent color on background image. The background image is working fine but the color is not placing.

I saw that the same question asked before. In my below code, I followed the same suggestion but not working for me.

How can I solve it?

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
color:white;
background-image: url("../logo/background/1(2).jpg");
background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an overlay effect, you can use `linear-gradient` property in `background`

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), url(https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/content/images/2021/06/w-qjCHPZbeXCQ-unsplash.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The background image is working fine but the color is not placing.

Yes because your background color is overlapped by background image.

To get a transparent layer over the image use the following code -

**CSS**

```
.background {
    background:url('..');
    position: relative;
}

.layer {
    background-color: rgba(248, 247, 216, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Also define width and height for background class.

**HTML**

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="layer">
    </div>
</div>
```